# Button dropdown can't switch after activate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The dropdown button is not working after initial click in bootstrap version 3.0:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="clearfix dropdown">
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="pull-right">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#supra">supraa</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#vespa">vespa</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="supra" class="tab-pane fade active in">
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
<div id="vespa" class="tab-pane fade">
<div id="container1" style=" height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: image button dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on my environment.

I suggest you to use the latest version on Bootstrap 3.3.6 and also clean your browser cache. Also make sure that you have all the dependencies include. (bootstrap.min.js, JQuery.min.js and bootstrap.min.css)

```
I used the same code as above. No change in code
```

The working demo of your code is here:  [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naga2raja/thtcg0y5/)